# Making a simple set of chloropleth maps in python -- colors not showing up

Tags: python, gis, shapefile, geopandas

Here is a shapefile that I'm trying to plot:

[link to a zipped shapefile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qitfb9tm9fhr7bj/foo.zip?dl=0)

Say I want to map the column `liab`.  I can see that it has a distribution of values:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
foo = gpd.read_file("foo.shp")
plt.hist(foo.liab)
```

[image]

But when I try to plot them, I can't see any colors:

```
foo.plot(column = "liab", legend = True)
```

[image]

What's the matter here?

Eventually, I want to make a grid of maps, similar to `facet_wrap` in `ggplot2` in R.  Is there a python analog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you why, but you need to specify you `vmin|max` for the colormap. I thought geopandas did this automatically, and it does for a small example, but not for your shapefile:

```
import geopandas

ax = (
    geopandas.read_file('/mnt/c/users/phobson/downloads/foo/foo.shp')
        .to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3083'})
        .plot(column="liab", legend=True, figsize=(10, 4),
              vmin=0.0, vmax=1)  # <-- magic is here
)
```

[image]